# Warning message: "In cor(...): the standard deviation is zero"

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, matrix, warnings, correlation

I have a single vector of flow data (29 data) and a 3D matrix data(360*180*29)

i want to find the correlation between single vector and 3D vector. The correlation matrix will have a size of 360*180.

```
> str(ScottsCk_flow_1981_2010_JJA)
 num [1:29] 0.151 0.644 0.996 0.658 1.702 ...
> str(ssta_winter)
 num [1:360, 1:180, 1:29] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
> summary(ssta_winter)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
    -2.8     -0.2      0.1      0.2      0.6      6.0 596849.0
```

This above is the structure of the vector and 3D matrix. 3D matrix has many values as Null.

```
> for (i in 1:360) {
+   for(j in 1:180){
+       cor_ScottsCk_SF_SST_JJA[i,j] = cor(ScottsCk_flow_1981_2010_JJA,ssta_winter[i,j,]) 
+    }
+ }
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

This part of code above is the code to find correlation. But it gives waring as

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In cor(ScottsCk_flow_1981_2010_JJA, ssta_winter[i, j,  ... :
  the standard deviation is zero
2: In cor(ScottsCk_flow_1981_2010_JJA, ssta_winter[i, j,  ... :
  the standard deviation is zero
3: In cor(ScottsCk_flow_1981_2010_JJA, ssta_winter[i, j,  ... :
  the standard deviation is zero
4: In cor(ScottsCk_flow_1981_2010_JJA, ssta_winter[i, j,  ... :
  the standard deviation is zero
5: In cor(ScottsCk_flow_1981_2010_JJA, ssta_winter[i, j,  ... :
  the standard deviation is zero
```

also, the result of the correlation matrix is all NULL. how did this happen?

```
> str(cor_ScottsCk_SF_SST_JJA)
 num [1:360, 1:180] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

I have used exact same code bfr with 350 flow vector and 360*180*350 matrix.
This code works perfectly.

Comment: For loop, all loop counter are not hard coded, hard coding here is just to simplify question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A few thoughts.

First, by using `apply()`, you can replace that nested loop with something like this:

```
cor_ScottsCk_SF_SST_JJA <- 
    apply(ssta_winter, MARGIN = 1:2, FUN = cor, ScottsCk_flow_1981_2010_JJA)
```

Second, it appears that >31% (`596849/(360*180*29)`) of the points in `ssta_winter` are `NaN` or (possibly) `NA_real_`. Given the return value of a correlation calculated on vectors that contain even a single `NaN`,

```
cor(c(1:3, NaN), c(1:4))
# [1] NA
```

isn't it likely that all those `NaN`s are causing `cor_ScottsCk_SF_SST_JJA` to be filled with `NA`s?

Third, as the warning messages plainly tell you, some of the vectors you are passing to `cor()` have zero variance. They have nothing to do with the `NaN`s: as the following shows, R doesn't complain about standard deviations of 0 when `NaN` are involved. (Quite sensibly too, since you can't calculate standard deviations for undefined numbers):

```
cor(c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN), c(1,1,1,1))
# [1] NA

cor(c(1,1,1,1), c(1,2,3,4))
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# In cor(c(1, 1, 1, 1), c(1, 2, 3, 4)) : the standard deviation is zero
```

Comment: But why it works previously, the same ssta data, a lot of NAs.

Comment: I'm curious about that as well, but have no way of knowing (or learning anything) without the data in front of me. Best of luck!

Comment: sorry, the problem is the ssta_winter array, the loop doesn't pass down, the data are saved corresponding to the last loop counter. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8):

This error might also be shown if a column has the same values for all observations. So, you might want to remove those rows.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses `library("psych")`

```
partial.r(sd,c("GPA","SAT"),"GRADE1",use = "complete.obs")
Warning Message:
 In cor(data, use = use, method = method) : the standard deviation is zero
```

sd contains NA for SAT.

```
partial.r(subset,c("GPA","SAT"),"GRADE1", use = "complete.obs")
no warnings
```

subset has NA's removed

Answer (score 1):

This warning can also occur if your data are too large for the format that they're being stored in. For example, if you have data in the trillions (for GDP, perhaps) and the data are being stored as 32-bit integers, R may recognize them as numeric, even though it's unable to do calculations with the data in that format (which is why it thinks the standard deviation is 0, even though all of your values are different).

If this is the case, when you view your data and hover over the column title, you might see a message like "column X: numeric with range undefined - undefined."

In this situation, dividing by a constant (say 1,000,000) to reduce the size of the values can fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

such a solution might work

```html
x <- rep(1, 5)    
y <- 1:5   

if(sd(x) == 0){
  print("denem")
  x[1] <- x[1] * .99
}
cor(x,y)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?