# correlation in R, when I do "pairwise.complet.obs" I get error "standard deviation is 0"

Tags: r, warnings, correlation, na

I am trying to do some correlation by group and have been using this very helpful thread:

[spearman correlation by group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791650/spearman-correlation-by-group-in-r)

however, there are some NA values in my 2 variables and in my groupings, so I get NA as the result for each group

so I tried this:

```
> j <- lapply(split(HTNPS, HTNPS$callcat), function(HTNPS){cor(HTNPS$NPS_int, 
HTNPS$holdtime_int,use="pairwise.complete.obs", method = "spearman")})
```

but then, although I get more sensible numbers, I get this warning:
    In cor(HTNPS$NPS_int, HTNPS$holdtime_int, use = "pairwise.complete.obs",  :
  the standard deviation is zero

As requested I have done dput(head(HTNPS,40) for the relevant columns

```
> dput(head(HTNPS[,20:24], 40))
structure(list(holdtime_int = structure(c(6, 11, 7, 7, 5, 7, 
6, 5, 3, 6, 3, 5, 6, 105, 7, 6, 353, 5, 6, 9, 6, 6, 12, 5, 5, 
5, 249, 5, 7, 11, 5, 7, 5, 290, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6), .Dim = c(40L, 
1L)), NPS_int = structure(c(1, NA, NA, 3, NA, 1, 1, 2, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 3, 2, 1, NA, 2, 4, 1, 2, NA, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1), .Dim = c(40L, 1L)), HTnot0 = structure(c(6, 
11, 7, 7, 5, 7, 6, 5, 3, 6, 3, 5, 6, 105, 7, 6, 353, 5, 6, 9, 
6, 6, 12, 5, 5, 5, 249, 5, 7, 11, 5, 7, 5, 290, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 
6), .Dim = c(40L, 1L)), callcat = structure(c(NA, NA, "CARD", 
"CARD", "GENERAL", "LOAN", "CHANGE DETAILS", "GENERAL", "LOAN", 
"CHANGE DETAILS", "LOAN", "CARD", "FUNDS TRANSFER", "FEE", "BALANCE", 
NA, "CARD", NA, NA, "STATEMENT", "CARD", "CARD", "GENERAL", "CARD", 
"CARD", "TERM DEPOSIT", "CARD", "GENERAL", "CARD", "CARD", "GENERAL", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "CARD", "CARD", "FUNDS TRANSFER", "GENERAL", 
"MyBusinessOverride"), .Dim = c(40L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
"callcat")), HTcat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(40L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "HTcat"))), .Names = c("holdtime_int", 
"NPS_int", "HTnot0", "callcat", "HTcat"), row.names = c(NA, 40L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please show us `dput(HTNPS)`. The problem is like due to what your data looks like after you do `split(HTNPS, HTNPS$callcat)`. For example, a situation like this will give you the same error message
: `In cor(c(0, 0), c(0, 0)) : the standard deviation is zero`

Comment: when I enter head(dput(HTNPS) (70,000 rows)

 call_start call_end interaction_id holdtime_int NPS_int HTnot0 callcat HTcat
1    42:14.0  48:58.0      304307105            6       1      6    <NA>     1
2    48:30.0  48:59.0      304306379           11      NA     11    <NA>     1
3    05:21.0  11:20.0      304160541            7      NA      7    CARD     1
4    15:31.0  27:01.0      304166503            7       3      7    CARD     1
5    25:47.0  37:32.0      304171781            5      NA      5 GENERAL     1
6    32:12.0  46:18.0      304175845            7       1      7    LOAN     1

Comment: @Rnovice  use `dput(head(HTNPS, 20))`

Comment: I've added it as an edit above

Comment: Your example produces only NAs. Give us something we can work with.

Comment: OK, I have tried again, this shoouldn't give all NAs

Comment: @Rnovice Check this link `<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124851/r-warning-message-in-cor-the-standard-deviation-is-zero>`

Answer (score 3):

If you do that split, many of your samples consist of only a single observation (after removing the NA's). Obviously there's no correlation to be calculated there.

The warning you get, is when one of both variables contains only a single value. In your example that is eg the data frame for `callcat==FUNDS TRANSFER`. `holdtime_int` has only a single value (being 6), so the standard deviation is 0 (hence the warning) and the resulting correlation is NA.

I don't know why you're looking at those correlations, but on the data you provided, they hardly make any sense to me. If you want to get rid of the warning, you can build in a check eg like this:

```
lapply(split(HTNPS,HTNPS$callcat), function(x){
  x <- na.exclude( x[c("holdtime_int","NPS_int")] )
  if(any(sapply(x, function(i)length(unique(i))) < 2 )){
    NA
  } else {
    cor(x[,1],x[,2], method="spearman")
  }
})
```

Which should give you the same result but without the warning. Note the use of `na.exclude` to get rid of the NA's.